# file_get_contents not working sometimes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authorization, file-get-contents

I have a simple file_get_contents using basic http auth:

```
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => 15,
            'header'  => array("Authorization: Basic "
                    . base64_encode("$user:$pwd"))
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

When I run this inside one PHP box, it arrives without the Authorization header. When I run it in another box, the header arrives.

What kind of info do I need to look for in order to find the cause?

Comment: The cause? It seems that if you give the auth it works, maybe it's protected ?

Comment: Check PHP version on both boxes.

Comment: PHP is 5.4.5 on both boxes

Comment: I want to clarify: I do give the user/pwd but if I output the $_SERVER variable on the server side, the user/pwd are missing.